# Variational formulation for an elliptic boundary value problem

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, elliptic-pde, calculus-of-variations

> I'm trying to determine the variational formulation of
> $$
> \begin{cases}
> -\Delta u(\mathbf{x})=1, & \mathbf{x}\in (0,1)\times (0,1) \\
> -\partial_{x}u(\mathbf{x})+c(\mathbf{x})u(\mathbf{x})=0, & \mathbf{x}\in \{0\}\times (0,1)\\
> \partial_{y}u(\mathbf{x})=0,  & \mathbf{x} \in (0,1)\times \{0\}\cup  (0,1)\times \{1\}\\
> \partial_{x}u(\mathbf{x})=0,  & \mathbf{x} \in\{1\}\times (0,1)
> \end{cases}
> $$
> and to prove that the resulting problem is well-posed.

I't's clear that the regularity conditions are satisfied also we can see that
\begin{eqnarray*}
    -\Delta u(\mathbf{x})&=&1\\
    -\Delta u(\mathbf{x})v(\mathbf{x})&=& v(\mathbf{x})\\
    -\int\limits_{\Omega}\Delta u(\mathbf{x})v(\mathbf{x})d\mathbf{x}&=& \int\limits_{\Omega}v(\mathbf{x})d\mathbf{x}
    \end{eqnarray*}
Using Green's formula, we obtain that
\begin{eqnarray*}
    -\int\limits_{\Omega}\Delta u(\mathbf{x})v(\mathbf{x})d\mathbf{x}&=& \int\limits_{\Omega}v(\mathbf{x})d\mathbf{x}\\
    \int\limits_{\Omega}\mathbf{\nabla u(x)}\cdot \mathbf{\nabla v(x)}d\mathbf{x}-\int\limits_{\partial\Omega}\gamma_{1}u(\mathbf{x})\gamma_{0}v(\mathbf{x})ds_{\mathbf{x}}&=&\int\limits_{\Omega}v(\mathbf{x})d\mathbf{x}
    \end{eqnarray*}
Now, the quantity $\displaystyle  \int_{\partial\Omega}\gamma_{1}u(\mathbf{x})\gamma_{0}v(\mathbf{x})ds_{\mathbf{x}}$ is equal to $\displaystyle \int_{\partial \Omega} v (\mathbf{\nabla u(\mathbf{x}) \cdot n})ds_\mathbf{x}$
I could find the  last cantity in terms of the **(BC)**, so the variational formulations is given by $$\color{blue}{\boxed{\text{Find:} \quad u\in H^{1}(\Omega): \quad a(u,v)=\ell(v), \quad \forall v\in V}}$$
with $V=H^{1}(\Omega)$ and where $$a(u,v):=\int_{\Omega} \mathbf{\nabla u(x)}\cdot \mathbf{\nabla v(x)}d\mathbf{x}-\int_{\partial \Omega} v (\mathbf{\nabla u(\mathbf{x}) \cdot n})ds_\mathbf{x}$$ and $$\ell(v):=\int_{\Omega} v(\mathbf{x})d\mathbf{x}$$

The quantity $\displaystyle \int_{\partial \Omega} v (\mathbf{\nabla u(\mathbf{x}) \cdot n})ds_\mathbf{x}$  I got it as

$$\int_{\partial \Omega} v (\nabla u \cdot n)ds_x = \int_{(0,1) \times \{0\} \cup (0,1) \times \{1\}} v \partial_x u \cdot n ds_x + \int_{\{1\} \times(0,1)}v \partial_y u \cdot n_2 ds_x + \int_{\{0\} \times (0,1)} v (c(x) u(x) + \partial_y u \cdot n_2 )ds_x$$

Now I'm studying if the variational-formulation of the boundary problem is well-posed: It's clear that $H^{1}(\Omega)$ is an Hilbert space, and it's clear that $a(u,v)$ is a bilinear form. *So, I need to prove that $a(u,v)$ is continous and coercive and $\ell$ is linar-continous form on $H^{1}(\Omega)$.*

I want to check continuity and coercitivity. For the first one I have

\begin{eqnarray*}
\forall (u,v)\in H^{1}(\Omega)\times H^{2}(\Omega): \quad |a(u,v)|&=&\left| \int_{\Omega} \mathbf{\nabla u(x)}\cdot \mathbf{\nabla v(x)}d\mathbf{x}- \int_{\partial \Omega} v (\mathbf{\nabla u(\mathbf{x}) \cdot n})ds_\mathbf{x} \right|\\
&\leq & \left|\int_{\Omega} \mathbf{\nabla u(x)}\cdot \mathbf{\nabla v(x)}d\mathbf{x}  \right|+ \left| \int_{\partial \Omega} v (\mathbf{\nabla u(\mathbf{x}) \cdot n})ds_\mathbf{x} \right|
\end{eqnarray*}

and for the coercitivity, I have

\begin{eqnarray*}
\forall v\in H^{1}(\Omega): \quad a(v,v)&=& \int_{\Omega} \mathbf{\nabla u(x)}\cdot \mathbf{\nabla v(x)}d\mathbf{x}- \int_{\partial \Omega} v (\mathbf{\nabla u(\mathbf{x}) \cdot n})ds_\mathbf{x}
\end{eqnarray*}

but I don't know how to continue from here. Can you help me? The test space is  $H^{1}(\Omega)$.

---

**Green's formula:** Let $\Omega$ a bounded open set in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ with border continous-Lipschitz $\partial \Omega$. Then,  $\forall v\in H^{1}(\Omega)$ and $u\in H^{2}(\Omega)$ we have $$\color{blue}{\boxed{\int\limits_{\Omega} v \Delta u=-\int\limits_{\Omega}\mathbf{\nabla u\cdot \nabla v}+\int\limits_{\partial \Omega}\gamma_{0}(v)\gamma_{0}(\mathbf{\nabla u)\cdot \nu}}}$$
where $\gamma_{0}(\mathbf{\nabla u})$ is the vector that is result of apply $\gamma_{0}$ to the components of $\mathbf{\nabla u}$.

**Lax-Milgram's theorem:** Let $V$ and real Hilbert space, $a(\cdot,\cdot)$ a bilineal form, continous and coercive on $V$ nd $\ell$ a lineal continous form on $V$. Then, there exists and unique element $u\in V$ that's solution of the variational problem.

Comment: Hint 1: your BCs can be written much more succinctly in terms of $\partial u/\partial n$. Hint 2: your $\int_{\partial\Omega}$ term wants to be part of $a(.,.)$.

Comment: @DCM Thanks, I added more details in my work about the solution for the problem. But, I can't continue in the proof about la continuity and coercivity of $a(\cdot, \cdot)$ and continuity in $\ell(\cdot)$.

Comment: This is more appropriate for math.SE